# Dynamic Pivot SQL Query for getting Fiscal week numbers

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Following is the code that I have built to calculate the failure rate of specific product.

- ASU QTY - Is the total products which are in Warranty
- Dispatch QTY - Is the Total Failure that the product has
- Fiscal_Week - Is the Week that the product Failed

If I need to get the Failure Rate - which is denoted as MDR

I need to Divide Dispatch QTY/ ASU QTY

In the code I have used the following

```
cast(isnull([Dispatch QTY],0) as float)/Cast(isnull([ASU QTY],0) as float) * 100  as 'MDR'
```

I need the following output

1. Dynamic Pivot Code by Fiscal Week as columns.

Full code to pull failure rate:

```
select @pivot = coalesce (@pivot + ',','')+ QUOTENAME(a.FISCAL_WEEK)
from ASU a 
left join dispatch b on a.FISCAL_WEEK = b.FISCAL_WEEK

--Dynamic SQL Query
Set @SQLQUERY = N'Select '+@Pivot+' from ASU a left Join dispatch b
on
a.FISCAL_WEEK = b.FISCAL_WEEK
Pivot(Sum(isnull([ASU QTY],0)
,Sum(isnull([Dispatch QTY],0)
For [a.FISCAL_WEEK] in ('+@Pivot+')) as P'

Exec sp_executesql @SQLQUERY
```

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You dont need dynamic SQL. As you have not provided sample data, I am putting pseudo code, which can be a reference for your implementation.

```sql
SELECT a.Fiscal_Week, FY1,FY2...
(d.DispatchQty/NULLIF(a.AsuQty,0)) * 100 AS MDR
FROM ASU as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dispatch as d
ON a.Fiscal_Week = d.Fiscal_Week
PIVOT
(
AVG(MDR)
FOR Fiscal_Week IN ([FY1],[FY2]...)
) as P
```